# Replacing a specific row of a dataframe with several rows of another dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a first dataframe `df1` that looks like the following one:

```py
    Id_Km Sector            var1    var2
0   1     Other             0       2
1   1     Resid             12      2
2   2     Cycl              4       6
3   2     Road              4       5
4   3     Other             5       3
5   3     Small_road        3       4
```

And a second one `df2` that contains the details of the `Road` variable:

```py
    year    detail  Road_type   car     time  percentage
0   2015    11      A           car1    10    0.41
1   2015    12      A           car2    4     0.02
2   2015    13      A           car3    3     0.08
3   2015    21      B           car4    7     0.13
4   2015    22      B           car5    1     0.08
5   2015    23      B           car6    22    0.08
6   2015    31      C           car7    10    0.15
7   2015    33      C           car8    9     0.05
```

I need to replace every `Road` variable in `df1` with `df2`.

Here's a detailed example of what I want to do:
Let's consider the following row of `df1`.

```py
    Id_Km Sector            var1    var2
3   2     Road              4       5
```

I would like to express `var1` with the percentage given in `df2` and replace `'Road'` with the corresponding `Road_type` variable. I would get something like this:

```py
    Id_Km Sector        var1       var2
3   2     A             4 * 0.41   5
3   2     A             4 * 0.02   5
3   2     A             4 * 0.08   5
3   2     B             4 * 0.13   5
etc.
```

So in the end my `df1` dataframe would be like this:

```py
    Id_Km Sector            var1    var2
0   1     Other             0       2
1   1     Resid             12      2
2   2     Cycl              4       6
3   2     A                 1.64    5
4   2     A                 0.08    5
5   2     A                 0.32    5
6   2     B                 0.52    5
7   3     Other             5       3
8   3     Small_road        3       4
```

I don't know how I should go about it. Applying the percentage values to `var1` is not too difficult but replacing one row by several others is being impossible to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes I am, I apologize I forgot to add it in the tags.

Comment: There is a replace function - `.replace(self, to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad')`  The documentation can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: What I understand from the documentation is that the .replace() function can only replace one value by another one. Here, I need to replace my 'Road' value with the eight lines of my second dataframe 'df2'. Can the function handle that?

Comment: Yes you need to select the column first which you want to append and then the data you want to append it too. ie: `df2.loc[df['Road_type'] *argument here*, 'Road_type'] = Road` or `var_1/2` etc..

Comment: I tried using the replace function but it doesn't seem to be working. I might be doing something wrong as I'm quite new to python. Would you happen to know if I can find some kind of detailled example somewhere?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-replace-to-replace-text-in-a-series/